# Higher-order derivatives in PyTorch increase in computation time exponentially

Tags: pytorch, derivative, autograd

In my application, I need to take the nth order mixed derivative of a function. However, I found that the torch.autograd.grad computation time increases exponentially as n increases. Is this expected, and is there any way around it?

This is my code for differentiating a function self.F (from R^n -> R^1):

```
def differentiate(self, x):
    x.requires_grad_(True)
    xi = [x[...,i] for i in range(x.shape[-1])]
    dyi = self.F(torch.stack(xi, dim=-1))
    for i in range(self.dim):
        start_time = time.time()
        dyi = torch.autograd.grad(dyi.sum(), xi[i], retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0]
        grad_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(grad_time)
    return dyi
```

And these are the times printed for each iteration of the above loop:

```
0.0037012100219726562
0.005133152008056641
0.008165121078491211
0.019922733306884766
0.059255123138427734
0.1910409927368164
0.6340939998626709
2.1612229347229004
11.042078971862793
```

I assume this is because the size of the computation graph is increasing? Is there any way around this? I thought I might be able to circumvent this issue by taking a functional approach (presumably obviating the need for a computation graph), using torch.func.grad. However, this actually *increased* the runtime of the same code! Am I not understanding torch.func.grad properly? Would a similar implementation in JAX provide any performance increase?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the output just 6 elements, like softmax, it has 6 inputs and 6 outputs, but it's derivative is a Jacobian matrix with shape 6x6，if you try to get the second derivative, it will be more than 6x6x6 and it is more than a three-dim hessian matrix.

and you should check jax, it's example, like this https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/examples/tanh.py

vector-to-vector gradient will be matrix or multi-dim matrix. so it's time used will increase exponentially.

```
Mathematically we can only take gradients of scalar-valued functions, but
autograd's elementwise_grad function also handles numpy's familiar vectorization
of scalar functions, which is used in this example.

To be precise, elementwise_grad(fun)(x) always returns the value of a
vector-Jacobian product, where the Jacobian of fun is evaluated at x and the
vector is an all-ones vector with the same size as the output of fun. When
vectorizing a scalar-valued function over many arguments, the Jacobian of the
overall vector-to-vector mapping is diagonal, and so this vector-Jacobian
product simply returns the diagonal elements of the Jacobian, which is the
(elementwise) gradient of the function at each input value over which the
function is vectorized.
```

or you can refer this [softmax_https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/657177292](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/657177292)

Comment: This is not the issue. First of all, it is a scalar-valued function, so the output is just of shape n (the input dimension). Furthermore, I am only interested in the mixed partial (not the full "hessian", or whatever that would be called for nth order derivatives instead of just 2nd order), so I index one of the dimensions before taking the next derivative. Consequently, the final output is still of shape n.